How can i give subcontent under a numbered footnote like this

How can i get this point in a existing footnote

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you edit your post to include a code showing what you tried?

Looks like a kind of itemize environment, maybe using package enumitem.

Use a standard itemize environment with \items:
Some document text\footnote{The results in this chapter are included in:
\begin{itemize}
  \item Some unknown location
\end{itemize}} more document text


